# UI-TAB SET == Active tab on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am working on a front end developement. I have tabs and these tabs are developed using "UI=TABSET"

So My question is , Lets assume i have 2 tabs.. tab1 and tab2. Firstly am on tab1..under tab there is a form where i entered details while moving to tab2..there will be modal popup with 2 buttons cancel and discard changes. If i click cancel..the details i have entered should remain same and stay on the same tab tab1 instead moving to tab2.

tab1 > entered details>click tab2 > modalpop>discard click> stay on tab1

Could you help me how to acheive this.

Comment: are you looking for step wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for step like feature you can try this

http://mgonto.github.io/angular-wizard/

As it works if step 1 is finished move to step 2 and so on

Easy to implement